# DeviceAdminReceiver: onChoosePrivateKeyAlias not called

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, device-admin

In my Android app (in Kotlin) I want to use `onChoosePrivateKeyAlias` ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver#onChoosePrivateKeyAlias(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String))) in my implementation of `DeviceAdminReceiver` to silently select the alias for a private key and certificate pair for authentication for a VPN.

I have successfully implemented `onEnabled` and `onDisabled`, however `onChoosePrivateKeyAlias` never seems to be called: Neither is the popup created by calling `KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias` suppressed nor can I find an entry in Logcat.

I was not able to find much about `onChoosePrivateKeyAlias` on stackoverflow or in general. 
Can anybody here help me?
Is there another intent filter I have to set I don't know about?

MyDeviceAdminReceiver:

```
import android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.util.Log

class MyDeviceAdminReceiver: DeviceAdminReceiver() {

    private var TAG = "MyDeviceAdmin"

    companion object {
        fun getComponentName(context: Context): ComponentName{
            return ComponentName(context.applicationContext, MyDeviceAdminReceiver::class.java)
        }
    }

    override fun onEnabled(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Device admin enabled")
     }

    override fun onChoosePrivateKeyAlias(context: Context?, intent: Intent?, uid: Int, uri: Uri?, alias: String?): String {
        super.onChoosePrivateKeyAlias(context, intent, uid, uri, alias)
        Log.d(TAG, "onChosePrivateKeyAlias called")
        return "Test User"
    }
}
```

Manifest (Snippet):

```
<receiver
    android:name=".security.MyDeviceAdminReceiver"
    android:description="@string/app_name"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.device_admin"
        android:resource="@xml/my_device_admin_receiver" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

my_device_admin_receiver:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin>
<uses-policies>
    <reset-password/>
    <force-lock/>
    <encrypted-storage/>
</uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

Comment: Anyone has any experience with `onChoosePrivateAlias`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DeviceAdminReceiver` needs to be a device policy controller (as a device or profile owner) to intercept requests with `onChoosePrivateKeyAlias`, as per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html#choosePrivateKeyAlias(android.app.Activity,%20android.security.KeyChainAliasCallback,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.security.Principal[],%20android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String)).

Comment: OK thanks a lot! Bit embarrassed though because I simply overlooked this in the documentation...